# dilemma about information storage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hello I am in need of guidance. sorry for the length of the message. This is my site http://lamiajoyee.com/wp/?page_id=147

if you click on the lands (the upper three in the corner), you will see a popup opens up with some pics and data.

these lands can be in two states, reserved and vacant. The difference is in the contents of the popup window. The page admin will set the status of the lands(vacant or reserved) in due time.

my problem is that i want to keep the status stored in a database and then check the status when the page is loaded/clicked. but the storage idea is not accurate. I have used 'contact form 7' and 'CFDB' with it. but there is a huge problem editing the data as you can only delete records using the free versions of CFDB or any other plugin as such.

Please suggest me a solution, I am not sleeping for the last three nights. Just store and check data. That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) - and add a custom field (true/false) for status.

Then in template file you could check: like this

```
if (get_field('house-status')) : 
    //your code that does something
else :
    //your other code that does something else
endif;
```